# Default Root user password question for MySQL on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install mysql on AWS EC2 instance, as I want to host a local website I built on cloud service. However, after I install mysql server, and try to install the secure service, it required a password where I haven't set any password yet

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation

Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root: 
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

After this, I try to start the mysql service in safe mode:

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

However, it showed command not found, where I thought this package should already installed while installing mysql.

I also tried just this

```
sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables
```

but it showed

```
sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
[1] 21732
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-54-104 ~]$ 2023-03-15T17:08:35.776704Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.32) starting as process 21733
2023-03-15T17:08:35.778744Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010123] [Server] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!
2023-03-15T17:08:35.779018Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-03-15T17:08:35.779580Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.32)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

After this, I tried to use

```
sudo mysqld --user=root
```

And it didn't showed anything, the terminal seems trying to figure things out, or just doing nothing. No message shows up.

If anyone can provide any help, or suggestion, that would be really helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Did you do as the error suggested?  *"Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!"* ?

Comment: yes, I followed this
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/default-privileges.html

And I tried mysql -u root --skip-password and also mysql -u root -p (which require password), all got accessed denied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out temp password for root:

```
sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log
```